# Dynamic control values for Slider2D

Tags: manipulate, slider

I would like to have a `Manipulate` object with a 2D slider whose boundaries change dynamically depending on other controls.

For linear sliders this seems to work as expected. As `i` increases the lower bound for `j` increases too.

```
Manipulate[j,{i, 1, 10, 1},{j, i, 10, 1}]
```

[image: sample code output]

But if I do this for a 2D slider control, I get something weird:

```
Manipulate[P,{a, 0, 1, 0.01},{P, {a, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image: sample code output]

If works if I nest two `Manipulate`s, but this doesn't look that pretty:

```
Manipulate[Manipulate[P, {P, {a, 0}, {1, 1}}], {a, 0, 1, 0.01}]
```

[image: sample code output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works "out of the box" for me using 10.0.1 on OS X 10.9.5 What V and platform are you using?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: This is Mathematica 9.0.0.0 on OS X 10.8.5.  If it works as expected for you on your newer setup, it sounds like this was a bug.  But the best kind of bug, that has a workaround and is fixed in the current release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
Manipulate[P, {a, 0, 1, 0.01}, {P, {a, 0}, {1, 1}, ControlType -> Slider2D}]
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, works! As I understand it, Mathematica tries to guess the best control type based on the parameter description, and `ControlType` can be used to force a particular control.  I'm surprised that it needs to be forced here but I'll take it.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, that's the way i also understand it.